# Moving UIView to new superview and back again from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, uiview

I have a custom `UITableViewCell` which has a custom `UIView` within it. When someone presses on the `UITableViewCell`, the `UIView` is transferred as a subview to a new `UIWindow`. Then when the `UIWindow` is dismissed I need the `UIView` to be transferred back into the same `UITableViewCell` that was selected.
I have tried using this code:

```
(self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!) as! ContentTableCell).replaceControls(self.expandedViewController.Controls)
```

where `replaceControls()` is a function inside my custom table cell that adds the given view as a subview and connects it to the appropriate `@IBOutlet`. `self.expandedViewController.Controls` is the custom `UIView`.

However this doesn't work and produces the error `CGAffineTransformInvert: singular matrix`.

Comment: Why move the view? Why not run an animation that just makes it look like the view moved?

Answer (score 0):

What about putting all the objects which are supposed to be set in two views in single one view with the `hidden` function and `CATrasition`.

- For example, you create the instance of `UIButton` with the `@IBAction fun flipViews()`. And you shall set the objects which are supposed to be set in BackSideView with `hidden` in your `viewDidLoad()` or your `storyboard`.

  `func flipViews() {
      UIView.beginAnimations("ViewSwitch", context: nil)
      UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.6)
      UIView.setAnimationCurve(.EaseInOut)
      if backSideObject1.hidden {
          frontSideObject1.hidden = true
          frontSideObject2.hidden = true
          frontSideObject3.hidden = true
          backSideObject1.hidden = false
          backSideObject2.hidden = false
          backSideObject3.hidden = false
      } else {
          frontSideObject1.hidden = false
          frontSideObject2.hidden = false
          frontSideObject3.hidden = false
          backSideObject1.hidden = true
          backSideObject2.hidden = true
          backSideObject3.hidden = true
      }
      UIView.setAnimationTransition(.FlipFromLeft, forView: view, cache: true)
      UIView.commitAnimations()
  }`

I hope my answer can help you.